# Using testdisk, how to extract the whole directory tree and filenames (deleted and good) only in ext4 partition?

Tags: testdisk

Using testdisk, how to extract the whole directory tree and filenames (deleted and good ones) only, in ext4 partition without saving the file itself in linux debian?